# Multithreaded code in AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Can there be a performance benefit to running multithreaded code in the doInBackground() function of the android AsyncTask class? This is a rough sketch of my plan:

```
private class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
{
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... vals)
    {
        Thread[] thrds = new Thread[NUM_THREADS];
        //Start all threads
        for(int i = 0; i < thrds.length; ++i)
        {
            thrds[i] = //Initialize threads
            thrds[i].start();
        }
        //Wait for all threads to finish
        for(int i = 0; i < thrds.length; ++i)
            thrds[i].join();
        //Post processing...
        return foo;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer res)
    {
        //Pass value back to UI class
    }
}
```

Will this spawn new threads which can be taken advantage of on a multi-core device? For instance, if the threads were each searching a (very-large) array for a maximum value, would there be a performance speed up on a multi-core device? Or will this result in something like "many-to-one" behavior.

One more thing, I want to multi-thread using Threads instead of calling multiple AsyncTasks, because the multi-threading will ultimately be handling domain level processing. I would strongly prefer to decouple the domain level processing from the UI classes so I can reuse the domain level classes with a different UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question, I too am curious if you can speed up tasks by taking advantages of multiple threads.

Comment: Depend on task. When calculations, there is obvious advantage (since num_cores calculation are performed simultaneously. But if your threads are accessing some low-speed resources (for example, the same disk storage) they can even slow down in comparison to single thread. In case of just memory scan (looking for maximum in array) it is depend on processor architecture, particularly on cache organization. Common cache for cores will be increased number of cache-misses.

Comment: @AterLux are you referring to multi-threading in general, or specifically to multi-threading within the doInBackground() function?

Comment: @nickandross in general. Not depending on where the threads was started. Just keep in mind, that AsyncTask it is just envelope for simple Thread, it starts one more thread too. Although, this thread will be in the waiting state on joins, and will not consume CPU resources. For more efficiency you can move calculations from one of the threads into doInBackground itself.

Comment: @AterLux thanks. I implemented my idea and looked at the running threads in Android Studio and the behavior [appears to be as you described](http://imgur.com/wNnRy7s). I started 4 threads and there was an additional thread for the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `AsyncTask`, spawn your own threads with `Thread#start()` or use a `java.util.concurrent.Executor`. It's unlikely you would want to combine these things.

`AsyncTask` class by default provides a single thread for your process that is distinct from the UI thread. The reason for this is mostly to ensure that tasks always finish in the same order they are started. If this isn't an issue for you then `AsyncTask` allows you to specify any other `Executor` to run on and provides a great one that is already tuned to have an ideally sized pool adjusted for the number of cores on your target processor.

Run an array of tasks like so:

```
AsyncTask[] tasks = ...
for (Task task : tasks) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
}
```

For the curious the code inside the Android platform looks like this:

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

/**
 * An {@link Executor} that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.
 */
public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can there be a performance benefit to running multithreaded code in the doInBackground() function of the android AsyncTask class?

No, for me your idea introduces even more confusion than regular `AsyncTask` does, see what Google says about "whats wrong with asynctask", for example [The Hidden Pitfalls of AsyncTask](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/).